# Does rubygems work on Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, apt-get

[This blog post](http://stakeventures.com/articles/2008/12/04/rubygem-is-from-mars-aptget-is-from-venus) of December 2008 says that rubygems is broken on Debian-based systems.

Does rubygems work cleanly on Ubuntu (for both 1.8 and 1.9)?

Comment: The post says nothing about rubygems being broken - just that some people are philosophically opposed to a package manager separate from apt. I've installed ruby and rubygems from apt-get in the normal way and it's absolutely fine.

Comment: @Nick "I always wondered why their rubygem package was intentionally broken. But never took the time to worry too much about it, when it’s easy to uninstall it and install it from source."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have it up and running on my ubuntu 9.04. So yes, it is working. I do not clearly remember but I thought I did it by apt-get, the easy way :).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about installing with apt-get, but I've never had any problems installing from [source](http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=126). Slicehost has a good article on [getting set up](http://articles.slicehost.com/2009/1/6/ubuntu-intrepid-ruby-on-rails).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. At least 1.8 does--I don't use Ubuntu enough to have any reason to install 1.9.

It might take a little bit of tweaking (Google any errors you find), but I've gotten it working fine, from the repositories, on 8.04 (Hardy Heron).